# JavaScript Function Difficulties

Tags: javascript, function

i have some code here that isn't working. And im not sure how i can make it work, some help would be awesome!

Here's the question so you understand where i started the code from.

**Question:**

Use object-oriented design to design a class called PhoneBill that calculates and prints the balance owed by each customer of a phone company during the billing period. Your PhoneBill class is to receive the customer's current balance and the total time, in minutes, of phonce calls during the billing period. The input time is to be validated and the cost of calls is to be calculated at 25c per minute. Your class is to print the input balance, the phone call time, the cost of the phone calls and the total amount due.

a. Design the class table

b. Write an algorithm for each operation in the table.

c. write a test or driver algorithm to test the solution

```
function PhoneBill()
 {
     this.bal;
     this.min;
     this.currCharge;
     this.Totaldue;
     this.currCharges=function()
     {
         this.currCharge=this.min*.25;
     }
     this.Totaldue=function()
     {
         this.Totaldue=this.bal+this.currCharge;
         return (this.Totaldue);
     }
     this.bal=function()
     {
         return (this.bal);
     }
     this.min=function()
     {
         return (this.min);
     }
 }

me=new PhoneBill();
me.balance=eval(prompt("Enter Current Balance: "));
me.minutes=eval(prompt("Enter Minutes Used: "));

document.write("Current Balance = $"+me.balance+"<p>");
document.write("Minutes Used = "+me.minutes+"<p>");
document.write("Current Charges = $"+me.currCharges()+"<p>");
document.write("New Balance = $"+me.Totaldue()+"<p>");
```

**The Error im Having:**

When i run it, i type in Current Balance (10) Minutes used (10)

And then it prints:

```
Current Balance = $10

Minutes Used = 10

Current Charges = $undefined

New Balance = $function() {return (this.bal); } NaN
```

*What in the world did i do to this code to get it to print that?*

Comment: NITPICK: return is not a method, drop the ( and )

Comment: The first four lines of your function don't do anything. If you wish to create properties with those names you have to assign a value. Then _don't_ assign a function to the same properties...

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: Is `this.min` supposed to be a value or a function?  Because `this.min=function(){return (this.min);}` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: your currCharges function isn't returning a value

Comment: You missed the return statement in your `currCharges` function. You also are redefining `this.Totaldue` to a function, and then returning it's value. I presume you want to return an actual monetary value, in which case you need to change either the name of your function, or the variable you're storing your data in.

Comment: Additionally as Louis mentioned, you are overwriting your TotalDue, bal and min properties to functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using this.Totaldue to define the function. And in this function you redefine it with: `this.Totaldue=this.bal+this.currCharge;`

So what you need to do is get the return values of these functions, not the definition.

```
  this.Totaldue=function()
 {
     return this.bal()+this.currCharge();
 }
```

But lol as i write this. You cannot let bal() en min() return their selves. That will make no sense. 
What you want is properties `this.bal = 'whatever';` and a function definition for ex. `this.getBal = function() { return this.bal; }` But because you are using getters only you could just get the property right away: `this.bal`. Definitely when you are inside the class itself, you don't need getters and setters.